# Can't Install wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I try to install WordPress filling required information it shows me like this. But if I put it as `admin@example.com` in username field it shows me same message

[image]

Comment: To be clear, have you tried putting the username as an email? (For example, `admin@mysite.com`)

Comment: yes, I tried it

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is cut off where it would show the 'Your Email' field that might be the cause for your error message. The complete 'Install – Step 5' screen looks like this:

[image]

(Source: [codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress))

**Site Title** = Give your site a name. This can be changed again later.

**Username** = Enter the user name for your first admin user. This can be your e-mail address, but it does not have to. The username can't be changed later. And … don't name it the simple to guess 'admin'! Think of something more unique.

**Password** = Enter a real strong password. Mix of special characters is not that im portant. Password length is what makes it secure. Best would be 20+ characters long. The password can be changed later again.

**Your Email** = Enter your admin's e-mail address here. **This is maybe the sport where a typo or something made it show the error message in your screenshot.** The e-mail address can be changed later again.

**Serach Engine Visibility** = For new websites you might almost always check this option so Google & Co. won't start indexing your half-done page while you're still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the box that says Your Email - and so I get this error because it doesn't ask me to put in an email address.

I know this thread is old, I am using wordpress 6.0.2

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1256316)